# How do I save a model with attribute of type 'date' in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

I'm trying to save an object containing a date attribute in Ember.js.

After calling createRecord() on the store, the new object is represented on the page, but the date attribute disappears from the page upon calling save(). All other attribute types on the model do not exhibit this appear-then-disappear behavior. Here is some example code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create()

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: () -> @store.find "post"

App.Post = DS.Model.extend
    time: DS.attr "date"
    body: DS.attr "string"

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
    actions:
        createPost: () ->
            body = @get 'newBody'
            post = @store.createRecord 'post',
                body: body
                time: Date.now()
            @set 'newBody', ''
            post.save()

App.Post.FIXTURES = [
    id: 1
    time: new Date("2013-9-30")
    body: "fixture post"
]
```

Please see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jordanmay/TvvMU/4/) for a demonstration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using `Date.now()` you should use `new Date()`.

`Date.now()` returns an integer which seems to give Ember problems.  `new Date()` returns an actual `Date` object which Ember can deal with.  Here's a slightly modified jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AJRts/